# array of strings only printing last element of array C

Tags: arrays, c

i created an array of strings called studentID and i want to put in a value i got from a csv into it this works but when i try and print all the values in the array only the last value i put in there is there for every value of the array.
`

```
    char** studentID = (char**)malloc(totalstudent * sizeof(char*));
    for( i=0; i<totalstudent; i++ ) {
        studentID[i] = (char*)malloc(max_size);
        }

    fp = fopen(student_file, "r");
    
    while(fgets(line,max_size,fp) != NULL){
        line[strcspn(line,"\n\r")] = '\0';

        ID = strtok(line,",");


        stringList[counter] = ID;
        printf("%s,",stringList[counter]);
        counter = counter + 1;
        printf("%d\n",counter);

    }

    for(i=0;i<21;i++){
        printf("%s\n",stringList[i]);
    }
```

`
this is the output

```
id,1
3444670,2
3611390,3
2939734,4
288301,5
1295620,6
757790,7
3149175,8
3173019,9
2890792,10
1274266,11
1274266
1274266
1274266
1274266
1274266
1274266
1274266
1274266
1274266
1274266
1274266
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @arka581 The pointer ID points inside the same character array line: ID = strtok(line,","); So all elements stringList[counter] = ID; will point to the content of the last string that was read in the array line.

Comment: so do you know how i could correct that

Comment: @arka581 You need to copy strings. extracted by calls of strtok

Comment: would i have to use strcpy

Comment: Where do you use the `studentID` array?

Comment: sorry the string list should be replaced with studentID

Comment: Try `stringList[counter] = ID;` --> `strcpy(stringList[counter], ID);`.

Comment: when doing that i get a segmentation fault(core dumped)